# browserHistory doesn't work in React-router

Tags: react-router

I was trying to change hashHistory to browserHistory in React-router, but I have a problem with it. I replaced hashHistory with browserHistory, but browser shows warning:

```
    Warning: [react-router] Location "/supmev2/index.html_ijt=3k35aa2cad6gsqau4hqdg9gvnp" did not match any routes
```

My App.jsx:

```
class App extends React.Component{
render(){
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Template}>
                <IndexRoute component={HomePage}></IndexRoute>
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    )
}
}
```

And this is my Template: {

```
class Template extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
                {this.props.children}
            <Footer></Footer>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: which version of the React router are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 3.0.3

Comment: what the url you using to access the application ? is it like localhost:8080/  or localhost:8080/index.html